# Cannot install .apk on phone

Tags: android, installation

I've just knocked together my first app, have released and signed it and transferred to my phone, but cannot get it to install on my phone - after going through the screen saying 'Do you want to install this application' and clicking install, I just get a message saying 'Application not installed' with no further explanation. I had checked the signing using `jarsigner -verify`.

I have uploaded the .apk to http://ubuntuone.com/p/ESB/ and obtained the log using the LogCollector app on my phone. The relevant extract is reproduced below.

```
Log Collector version: 1.1.0
Device model: HTC Desire
Firmware version: 2.2
Kernel version: 2.6.32.15-gf9c0527
htc-kernel@and18-2 )
#1 PREEMPT Fri Jul 23 17:26:53 CST 2010
Build number: FRF91

08-31 10:18:21.289 I/ActivityManager(   93): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///sdcard/blanket.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity }
08-31 10:18:21.359 I/PackageParser(20453): uk.co.oketchup.blanketsquare: compat added android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
08-31 10:18:21.379 D/skia    (20453): --- decoder->decode returned false
08-31 10:18:21.669 I/ActivityManager(   93): Displayed activity com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity: 331 ms (total 331 ms)
08-31 10:18:22.059 D/PowerManagerService(   93): New lightsensor value:640, lcdValue:192
08-31 10:18:22.390 D/SynchronizationService(20285): Checking preferences
08-31 10:18:22.769 I/ActivityManager(   93): Starting activity: Intent { dat=file:///sdcard/blanket.apk cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress (has extras) }
08-31 10:18:22.849 D/skia    (20453): --- decoder->decode returned false
08-31 10:18:22.999 D/dalvikvm(20459): GC_EXPLICIT freed 419 objects / 23968 bytes in 74ms
08-31 10:18:23.089 D/PackageParser(   93): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl73677.tmp
08-31 10:18:23.099 I/PackageParser(   93): uk.co.oketchup.blanketsquare: compat added android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
08-31 10:18:23.129 I/ActivityManager(   93): Displayed activity com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress: 320 ms (total 320 ms)
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): Exception reading res/layout/main.xml in /data/app/vmdl73677.tmp
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): java.io.IOException
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:207)
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:432)
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:130)
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.InputStreamHelper.readFullyAndClose(InputStreamHelper.java:174)
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:307)
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:385)
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): at android.content.pm.PackageParser.loadCertificates(PackageParser.java:338)
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:509)
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): at com.android.server.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:5961)
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): at com.android.server.PackageManagerService.access$2100(PackageManagerService.java:138)
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): at com.android.server.PackageManagerService$5.run(PackageManagerService.java:4819)
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): Caused by: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: data error
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateImpl(Native Method)
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:255)
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:188)
08-31 10:18:23.139 W/PackageParser(   93): ... 14 more
08-31 10:18:23.149 E/PackageParser(   93): Package uk.co.oketchup.blanketsquare has no certificates at entry res/layout/main.xml; ignoring!
08-31 10:18:23.269 D/dalvikvm(   93): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5970 objects / 337960 bytes in 107ms
08-31 10:18:24.729 I/InstallAppProgress(20453): Finished installing uk.co.oketchup.blanketsquare
```

Many thanks for your help.

---

*Edit 02/09/2010*
I have modified the main.xml file again by removing pretty much all the whitespace. It still does not install but is not quite the same error: it's claiming there is a zip file error although I notice that certificates do appear further down the list. If this is not something I'm obviously doing wrong, would it be better if I raised on android developers mailing list?

```
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): Exception reading /data/app/vmdl73692.tmp
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): java.io.IOException
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:207)
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:432)
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:130)
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.InputStreamHelper.readFullyAndClose(InputStreamHelper.java:174)
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): at java.util.jar.JarFile.readMetaEntries(JarFile.java:360)
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:237)
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:218)
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:471)
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): at com.android.server.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:5961)
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): at com.android.server.PackageManagerService.access$2100(PackageManagerService.java:138)
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): at com.android.server.PackageManagerService$5.run(PackageManagerService.java:4819)
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): Caused by: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: data error
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateImpl(Native Method)
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:255)
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:188)
09-02 17:33:32.819 W/PackageParser(   93): ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I've seen corrupted .apks that won't load on a device, with weird IOExceptions. Following these steps in Eclipse seems to prevent the problems I've seen:

1. Make sure that Project -> Build Automatically is turned off (that is, unchecked)
2. Project -> Clean..., select "Clean All Projects", make sure the "Start a Build Automatically" checkbox is unchecked, and click OK.
3. Use File -> Export -> Android -> Export Android Application to create the APK

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that your apk is not signed.

If you are using eclipse you would need to sign the application while building. You can sign the application using the your keys , if you have, or you can create an apk with debug keys provided with eclipse.

Procedure:

Rtclick on project> Android tools> Export Signed application package" > specify the keystore location (for debug keystore look at the home directory of your computer, the password for debug key is android).

Comment: The question says "I had checked the signing using `jarsigner -verify`." How can you be sure that the apk is not signed?

Answer (score 0):

There is some exception being raised while trying to sign the file named main.xml

**Exception reading res/layout/main.xml in /data/app/vmdl73677.tmp**

Try to delete or recreate that file and then compile/sign and run the application

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android%20Market/thread?tid=11b65a3c2807848a&hl=en

Comment: I made some minor changes to the file and recompiled/signed. However I get exactly the same error.

I don't think I can delete the file because it's needed for the layout.

Comment: can u try remaining the file and check if the exception is being thrown on the same file

Comment: I tried renaming it to main2.xml and changing the reference to setContentView. I have now got a slightly different message

    Exception reading res/layout/main2.xml in /data/app/vmdl73684.tmp
     java.io.IOException: Invalid attribute 61
     at java.util.jar.InitManifest.readName(InitManifest.java:150)
     at java.util.jar.InitManifest.readHeader(InitManifest.java:115)
     at java.util.jar.InitManifest.initEntries(InitManifest.java:75)
     at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:234)
     at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:116)
[etc]

Comment: As of now the error still points to the same xml file. It is pointing to main2.xml at this point i am unable to help you better. One alternate approach you can try signing apk directly from Eclipse(using android plug-in)

Comment: Use the eclipse signer. Just export your app as an android app

Comment: Thanks both. I've just tried using Eclipse but sadly I get the same error.

Comment: I had the same error, and exporting as a signed package resolved this for me as Falmarri suggested.